# How do I kill all of the enemy sprites on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a second level to my game, so when you get > 100 points it will delete all of the enemy sprites on the screen and then start the next level. I don't know how to delete them all. I do have an enemy sprite group called `enemies`, but I dont know how to use it in relation to `.kill()`.

Comment: This might help: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102437. You can call .kill() on each of them

Comment: Did my answer work? If so, please accept the answer

Comment: @RhinoRunner, please reply as to whether my answer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through all sprites in the group and call `.kill()` on each one such as:

```
for sprite in group:
    sprite.kill()
```